# Should I use code splitting on every component in vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, code-splitting

I have an application in `vue` with typescript. I saw when I use `import` to load component then I got component-bundle with all the code of component inside.

I wonder if should I do this for every component I want to load, for example: I have app.vue inside I have toolbar.vue and drawer.vue. in my router components I have others vue components.

What I'm afraid that gonna happened is app.js is loaded then components inside the route definition(500k), then I get the toolbar component (1.5mb). and I'll get flashing screen weird.

So, should I use splitting bundle for every component in my app?

Answer (score 2):

You can do code splitting if you are not expecting that particular component to be re-used for every page.

Take for example the `Header` and `Footer` component. Since they will be used in almost all of the pages, there is no reason to code split as you want it to be loaded along with the bundle for all pages.

---

Take for example you have a component where it has a `Blog Widget`. This component will only load in the `/blog` page. Therefore, this is a good use case to be using code splitting as you do not need the `Blog Widget` to be bundled in other pages except in the `/blog` page.

I can only provide you with a generic answer and using the `Header` and `Footer` components are the best way to express different use cases. As for the rest of the components, you have to decide for yourself if it is worth to code split or not.